# Adding Python list as new column into Pandas DataFrame + "ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a Python list of Pandas Dataframes and a list of lists containing numbers.

```
df_list = [df,df,df,df] #Four Dataframes 
id_list = [[123, 452],[342, 533, 222, 402, 124],[125, 263, 254, 44, 987, 78, 655, 741, 165, 597, 26, 15, 799, 100],[154, 122, 563]] ##Four lists
```

As shown below, I tried to insert each list in **id_list** as a new column ('order_id') into each Dataframe from **df_list**.

```
for df in df_list:
   print(len(df.index)) #checked the number of rows for each Dataframe to ensure it matches the size of each list in id_list
   for id in id_list:  
      df['order_id'] = id
```

After I run this code, I get the "ValueError:Length of values does not match length of index". I made sure the length of each **id_list** matches that of each DataFrame. What can I do to resolve this error and successfully add each id_list into each Dataframe?

Thank you!

Comment: You are using a *nested* loop, you need `for df, id_ in zip(df_list, id_list): df['order_id'] = id_`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga - Thank you for your comment; it worked. Quick question: is there a particular reason why you added an underscore in the id_ variable?

Comment: because `id` is the name of the built-in `id` function. It is best not to shadow built-in functions. So, another example might be `max`, which is a perfectly reasonable variable name, but it is already taken by the `max` function. So as not to shadow it, one might just use `max_`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga - Got it. Thank you for the explanation. Appreciate it.